# Apex batch Execute method not getting invoked

Tags: apex, batch

I am trying to write a sample Batch job which operating on `MyOrder__c` , this is my custom object:

```
global class BatchTest implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{

   global String query;
   global id[] i;
   global id e;
   List<MyOrder__C> lm=new List<MyOrder__C>();


global BatchTest(id[] t){

    System.debug('in constructor');
    this.i=t;


}

global Database.QueryLocator start (Database.BatchableContext bc){

    System.debug('in start');
    query= 'select name,TestQQ__c from MyOrder__c where id in :i';
    System.debug('listt of ids'+i);
    System.debug('my queryyy   '+ query);
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);

}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bd, list<MyOrder__c> l){
      System.debug('inside execute method '+l);

    for(MyOrder__c a: l)
    {
        lm.add(a);
        System.debug('name of Order'+ a.Name);
        a.TESTQQ__c=true;
    }
    update lm;

}
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){



}

}
```

Could anyone help me here finding the issue why its not getting going inside execute method?

Comment: In your start method, what is returned by your `System.debug('listt of ids'+i);` line? Is the `i` list filled?

Comment: do you have any `MyOrder__c` records?